# number of non trivial group homomorphisms

Tags: group-theory

Let G be group {+1,-1,+i,-i} with multiplication of complex numbers as composition. Let H be quotient group Z/4Z. Find the number of non trivial group homomorphisms from H to G.

My attempt:
 G is cyclic group of order 4, H is isomorphic to $ Z_4$ therefore it is also cyclic group of order 4. We have number of homomorphism =gcd(4,4)=4. But deleting trivial homomorphism we get answer 3.

Is above process right? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$G$ is cyclic, generated by $i$. Thus any homomorphism $\varphi\colon G\rightarrow H$ is uniquely determined with the image of $i$, provided order of $\varphi(i)$ should divide $4$. Since order of every element of $H$ divides $4$, we can send $i$ to any element of $H$ to obtain a homomorphism. There four homomorphisms (three non-trivial).

---

Recall: $f\colon G\rightarrow H$ a homomorphism, and $o(x)=m$ in $G$ implies $o(f(x))$ divides $m$.

Comment: thanks a lot for providing reason behind this.